# iOS - 1000's of literal strings, how to handle?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have a few thousand literal strings in my app.

I currently have them all listed in my .m file.

I don't have a problem doing it this way, and it works for my app.

Is this not a best practice?  Should I house my string data in an external DB?

Thank You.

Comment: How are the strings used in your app? Are they words, or entire paragraphs? Do you use only a subset of the strings at a given time, e.g. English vs. French vs. Italian?

Answer (score 1):

Several thousand literal strings sounds annoying, but that's the worst of it. A database probably would be overkill and hard to maintain. So long as you can localize your app when/if you need to, it should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is the kind of thing SQLite was MEANT for.

The minute you instantiate that object, all those strings are taking up memory, including the vast majority of which you probably won't use on any particular trip through the app. I'd sure rather have a database I could just query up the ones I need.

Comment: Maybe the strings are keys to a dictionary, labels, or parameters and response strings for some network protocol. Does it really make sense to query a database to get those? I'm not saying that you're wrong, but it's hard to know without more information about how the strings are used.

Comment: I don't really want to work with a flat text file of "a few thousand" *anythings*. There are TOOLS for that!